# Начальное форматирование для нескольких таблиц в Power BI одновременно?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

В **Power BI** я импортировал несколько таблиц одного типа (около 50 таблиц из разных источников). Например 10 таблиц из одного источника, еще 10 таблиц из другого источника. И так далее
[image]

---

Для каждой таблицы ( **Ast10, Ast11, Ast12** .... и т. д.) мне нужно выполнить одинаковое начальное форматирование:

- Удалить пустые строки
- Переместить первую строку в заголовки
- Выбрать только 8 определенных столбцов в каждой таблице.

Все эти таблицы одинаковы по типу: одинаковые столбцы, одинаковые пустые строки вверху, одинаковые столбцы для выбора, но внутри разные данные.

---

Когда я выбираю несколько таблиц (с помощью Shift или Ctrl) одновременно начинаю форматировать:
[image]

Затронута только одна таблица.

---

Как я могу просто выполнить начальное примитивное форматирование всех таблиц в Power BI?
То есть в каждой таблице удалены пустые строки, первые строки приведены к заголовку, в каждой таблице выбраны только определенные столбцы? Есть ли способ сделать это без 50-кратного повторения?